# How to correctly duplicate my field in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a doggy treat application using html and javascript. I have a section called `Features` that I would like in its own section below `Product Options`. I am trying to duplicate the code but unfortunately I am having no success. I am not a professional at javascript by any means so if anyone can please take a look at my code and see what I am doing wrong, it would be much appreciated.

The problem is my `(treat.features)` pulled from mySQL is not correctly displaying in HTML on the front-end. Nothing is appearing.

http://jsfiddle.net/3hz3tsok/

```
function listAddSymptomsDb(tx) {
    var category = getUrlVars().category;
    var mainsymptom = getUrlVars().mainsymptom;
    tx.executeSql('SELECT DISTINCT Add_Symptom FROM "Main Database" WHERE Category="' + category +
                  '" AND Main_Symptom="' + mainsymptom +'"',[],txSuccessListAddSymptoms);
}

function txSuccessListTreatment(tx,results) {
    //console.log("Read Treatment success");
    var tubeDest = "#products";
    var len = results.rows.length;
    var treat;
    for (var i=0; i < len; i = i + 1) {
        treat = results.rows.item(i);                                

        //console.log("Specialty Product #1: " + treat.Specialty1);
        if(treat.Specialty1){
            $("#products").append(formatProductDisplay('specialty1',     treat.Specialty1, treat.PurposeSpecialty1, treat.DosageSpecialty1, treat.Ingredients, '1'));
        }

              if(treat.Specialty1){
            $("#features").append(formatProductDisplay('feature', treat.features, '1'));
        }            

        $('#products').listview('refresh');
        $('#features').listview('refresh');
        $('.print').bind("click", function(){
                         printIt();
                         });
        //debug print content
        //console.log($('#printable').html());
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your problem again?

Comment: For some reason my features (treat.features) is not displaying at all on the front-end in html.

Comment: this doesnt even exist

Comment: Could you put your code into the question itself? It helps in the case that this link every breaks, we prefer to have questions be self-contained.

Comment: I've added the code, thank you. Georgi can you explain more in-depth?